# SQL Server password behaviour

Tags: sql-server-2008

1. Is there a way to find logins with blank (NULL) passwords? In SQL 2000, I could use Syslogins table to query for password = NULL but in SQL2005 and 2008, NULL passwords have a value in the password column.
2. Is there are a way to globally enforce password policy (complexity, expiration etc) which was introduced in SQL2005? I know we can set for each login but if we wanted to enforce the policy globally (at GPO level or SQL Instance level) can we do it such so that when someone creates a login password policies (and complexity) are enforced? In other words there will not be a choice to not use password policies.

Jay

Answer (score 0):

http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=966

That should get you started. You really have to manage this stuff "manually" (meaning using scripts/contraints). I have never needed to do this so cannot offer you any advice. But I can say for sure password policy management was not introduced until 2005.